# What is the best way as far writing a batch processor using Service fabric?

Tags: service-fabric-actor, azure-service-fabric

We need to be able to work through the result recordset of a stored procedure.  The processing will be the same for each individual record, we would like to have multi threading and not run into any locking.  Would you recommend actor or stateful here?

Comment: Tough to answer without more info. How big is the recordset likely to be? Can it be processed one record at a time, or does it need to be processed in an all-or-nothing fashion?  How long does processing each record take?  Do they need to be processed in order?   If the record set isn't very big, I'd probably use a StatefulService that spawns off a number of Actors.  Especially if the processing requires you to access an external service of some kind. It keeps the code pretty simple and allows you to easily stand up new Actor types if some records need new processing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Cursory answer without more info:

Create a stateful service to receive requests to process the recordsets (include the recordset to be processed, or the procedure to get the recordset, or store it somewhere so it can be recalled). Then, inside the stateful service, iterate through the recordset parsing out the processing to individual actors. You can generate random IDs if you don't care about how many actors, or you could constrain the processing to a finite set. If you choose the former, you have to think about scale - how many processors can safely run at the same time without scaling out? If you use the later, you need some sort of queue processing or pub/sub infrastructure in the actors so you can divy out the work and make sure it all gets done.